# Gradle (Android Studio) - Null extracted folder for artifact: ResolvedArtifact

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I'm trying to create an Android build using Android Studio. The platform is React Native v0.61.5 (Migrated to AndroidX), but I am getting the following error. I also tried cleaning the build multiple times and invalidating caches. I even tried deleting the .aar file mentioned in the given location, but with no success:

```
Null extracted folder for artifact: ResolvedArtifact(componentIdentifier=androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.4.0, variantName=null, artifactFile=/Users/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.annotation/annotation-experimental/1.4.0/c7a2038d831d0cfbfb9a440890b287c2e839ecf/annotation-experimental-1.4.0.aar, extractedFolder=null, dependencyType=ANDROID, isWrappedModule=false, buildMapping={__current_build__=/code/mobileapp/android}, mavenCoordinatesCache=com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.dependencies.MavenCoordinatesCacheBuildService$Inject@24d6a856)
```

Not sure what is causing this issue, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The "Null extracted folder for artifact: ResolvedArtifact" cautioning is the exact problem that I recently ran into when using Gradle with Android Studio.  I looked into the issue and discovered a workaround that fixes it successfully. Here’s a step-by-step guide on how to use the solution:

- Open the gradle.properties file in your project.
- Look for the line that says android.enableJetifier=true.
- Comment out this line by adding a `//`, so it looks like this: `// android.enableJetifier=true`.
- Save your gradle.properties file.
- In IntelliJ for Android, go to **File > Invalidate Caches..** and select **Invalidate and Restart**. This action will clear the cache and restart IntelliJ for Android.

In my case, I had to set `android.enableJetifier=true` to enable automatic conversion of third-party libraries to AndroidX compatibility. Additionally, I included `android.jetifier.ignorelist=annotation-experimental-1.4.0.aar` in the gradle.properties file because I am using Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) version 4.2, which requires this adjustment. As for projects utilizing AGP version 4.1, you should instead use `android.jetifier.blacklist=annotation-experimental-1.4.0.aar`.

By following these steps, the issue was resolved for me. The solution was initially discovered in a discussion on the Google Issue Tracker. Further information regarding this issue can be found [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/294342862).